# Where is the margin/spacing coming from?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 inline flex container in [this test](https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-layout/target/test/html/).  I'm specifically referring to the test that says ***Then*** `The flex containers are laid out inline.`

There is a little bit of space between the container, but when I look in the chrome developer tools at the at the margin box I don't see a margin being rendered on either container, so I'm just curious where the space comes from?

Here's a picture of the test, just to make sure it's clear:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that `inline-flex` is similar to `inline-block` in the way that it takes into account the whitespace that you have in your HTML markup between the containers. So juste remove the whitespace between the `u-flex-inline`:

```
<div class="Test_render">
  <div class="u-flex-inline
              u-background-color-orange
              u-padding-1rem
              u-border-right-style-solid
              u-border-right-width-2px">
              First container</div><!--
  --><div class="u-flex-inline
              u-background-color-orange
              u-padding-1rem">
              Second container</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Funny - Dude it comes from the space you added :) - Thanks!